# How do I create a proper new local and remote branch combination in EGit?

Tags: git, egit

I would like to do the following in EGit:

```
$ git checkout -b newbranch
$ git push -u origin newbranch
```

This gives me a new local branch, pushes it to the upstream server and **creates the right tracking reference**. How do I do the same in EGit?

Comment: EGit 3.2 finally (February 2014) offers to set the upstream branch when pushing! See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10111655/6309)

Answer (score 9):

For the first operation, you can read the EGit manual "[Creating a New Local Branch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Creating_a_New_Local_Branch) "

> Select Team > Switch To... > New Branch

[image: new branch dialog]

For the push, see [Vogella's Egit tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#github_push), but also the "[Push ref specification](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Ref_Specifications)"

[image: push a branch]

Note: [robinst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305973/robinst) has opened [bug 378960](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378960) "Allow to configure upstream in Push Branch wizard" (mentioned in "[EGit - set up remote tracking correctly when creating a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10619912/6309)").

> The problem is that this (configuring the upstream on push) is not yet done
>   automatically when first pushing a branch.
>
> For now you have to right click on the branch in the Git Repositories view and choose "`Configure Branch`", where you can set up the upstream configuration.

---

Note: [bug 378960](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378960) has been marked as resolved (February 2014) in [Egit 3.2](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/3.2#Features):

> Push Branch / Initial Push wizard simplifies pushing a branch and also **allows upstream configuration for new branches created by the push operation**:

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/6/6f/Egit-3.2-PushBranchWizard.png]

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is not helpful, since its result is not the one I asked for. This way, the new branch still merges from the branch it was created from (e.g. `branch.newbranch.merge = refs/heads/master`), but I would like to have a proper upstream tracking reference, like the one the `-u` flag creates.

Comment: @neelance ok I will check that tomorrow

Comment: @neelance I did check, but didn't find an obvious solution for now.

Comment: Opened a bug about being able to do `git push --set-upstream` here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378960

Comment: For now you have to right click on the branch in the Git Repositories view and choose "Configure Branch", where you can set up the upstream configuration.

Comment: @robinst: interesting. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The UI location for creating a new branch seems strange to me.

In the `Git Repository` tab, select a branch you want to create a branch from it `right click` and then you will see `Create Branch`

[image]